# How do you get a UUID from a a device on the grub2 prompt?

Tags: grub2, uuid

I'm trying to perform some grub2 troubleshooting related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226364/half-the-time-linux-drop-into-busybox-the-rest-of-the-time-the-boot-happens-nor) question, and as part of the troubleshooting I'm trying to figure out what grub can see during the boot. How can I get the UUID of, say (hd0,msdos1) while I'm at the grub2 prompt?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `ls -l` command should be revealing.

Comment: For those wondering why [`ls -l` would do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITURg.png), it's because the GRUB prompt supports [an `ls` command that can list devices](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/ls.html).

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically, this can be queried with the `probe` command, e.g.:

```
probe --fs-uuid (hd0,gpt6)
```

The result can also be assigned to a variable with `--set`:

```
probe --set devuuid --fs-uuid (hd0,gpt6)
echo $devuuid
```

Answer (score 1):

From GRUB command line, `cat (hd0,gpt9)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` should reveal the UUID. Remember to use `"set pager=1"` to scroll page by page